# PHP's PDO prepared statement: am I able to use one placeholder multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, placeholder

I'd like to perform the following query:

```php
    SELECT
      *,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab2` WHERE `parent` = :id) AS `sum`
    FROM `tab1`
    WHERE `id` = :id
```

As you can see `:id` placeholder appeared twice in the query. So if I'd try to execute this statement with:

```
$q->execute(['id'=>$row_id]);
```

I'm receiving the error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

So I have to rewrite the prepared query and execute array with :id1 and :id2 placeholders which looks a bit stupid for me.

Is it the only way to use one placeholder in several places of the prepared statement?

Comment: @DarkBee *Sort of*. That link that you posted as a possible duplicate, is using `SELECT :Param`. The initial problem is that the OP was trying to bind a column. This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/ explains and specifies *"Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO"*, from the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/ on the same page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- true, but the answer that is marked on that page states that a placeholder only can be used once.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm surprised. Why is there such limitation?! Is it MySQL limitation?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that it's not a reason to turn on PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES?

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I agree and that is why my comment started with "Sort of" ;)

Comment: Cant really understand `SELECT SUM(*) FROM tab2` ?

Comment: @VladaKatlinskaya The thing is about not being able/allowed to bind a table/column, is that MySQL doesn't know "ahead of time" what it is that it's supposed to bind (`:value="something";` is invalid). That's why using pre-defined variables, is a way around it. A bind is associated with a pre-defined variable or POST/GET variable, so now it knows what to bind, because the variable(s) have already been assigned ahead of time. So, doing `$value = "column"; SELECT $value` is allowed, but `SELECT :value` is not.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you're right - that's not a good example. I changed the syntax in the OT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) states that

> [y]ou cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Since it's generally better to leave emulation mode off (so the database does the prepared statement), you'll have to use `id_0`, `id_1`, etc.

Comment: Unless the statement is executed multiple times using different values, real prepared statements are not necessarily better.

Comment: Not necessarily better, but they offload the parameter parsing/quoting logic to the database, which is often faster than PHP (at least for those tasks).

Comment: There is no parameter quoting when using real prepared statements.