# PDO - Getting error while trying to bind values in BETWEEN on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping, between

I'm trying to make a select statement using PDO and MySql. I have the following code:

```
$this->bind[':created'] = "'" . (new DateTime('First day of this month'))->format('Y-m-d') . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'"; 
$this->where[] = "created  BETWEEM :created";
```

As you can see, i'm putting a quote character wrapping the date, following [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) but PHP is escaping it and i'm getting an error.

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'created  BETWEEN '\'2015-07-01\' AND \'2015-07-24\'' '

So, how can i use a range date with PDO::bindValue()?

Being more specific, i want to get this result:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-24'

rather than:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE created BETWEEN '\'2015-07-01\' AND '\2015-07-24\''

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a typo just here? `created  BETWEEM :created` Error message seems correct.

Comment: Why not split it into 2 params, and then bind them seperately.

Comment: @Sean yea thats what I was thinking. `$this->where[] = "created  BETWEEN :createdF and :createdT";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

binding is for SINGLE values. you're trying to bind multiple values. You need:

```
... WHERE foo BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

and two bind calls.

Remember, a placeholder is basically kind of like a variable, except the DB knows that this "variable" can only represent a single value. it will **NOT** pick apart the value you pass in and try to make it fit the statement, so

```
foo BETWEEN :thingie
```

is no different than

```
foo BETWEEEN '$var'
```

as far as number-of-values-being-inserted is concerned.

Comment: or even `... BETWEEN :created AND:created` no?  I to think this yours is clearer - just want to distinguish what actual issue was with what OP was doing.

Comment: @ficuscr reusing the same placeholder does not work unless emulation mode is on see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461763/phps-pdo-prepared-statement-am-i-able-to-use-one-placeholder-multiple-times and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432084/pdo-parameterized-query-reuse-named-placeholders

Comment: @ficuscr: what'd be the point of betweening the same value? might as well just have `foo = :created` at that point.